# mysql update entire null column that has foreign key checks

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

There must be a way to update a mysql field from a NULL value to another value, without using SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0, correct?

I tried this:

```
update tablename set fieldname = "textstring" where fieldname is null;
```

and that seemingly changed the value of the column only when I queried for results of that column, not when I queried for entire rows from the table. How can I add another condition that would satisfy the referencing table constraint, in order to update the field?

Here is the basic structure:

```
{Database:businesses,{company:[id,name,address,phone],employee:[id,company(fk),role]}}
```

In the employee table, id, and role fields are already filled, but company values are all NULL. I want to replace NULL in this field with "somestring". I am using mysql 5.5 in a Linux Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: "changed the value of the column only when I queried for results of that column, not when I queried for entire rows from the table" What?

Comment: when I queried >select company from employee, I saw the values "somestring" - however, when I queried >select * from emploee, the values of the company field still showed Null, indicating that they had not been changed after all..

Comment: I find that very unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

I never got an answer to this one, so I ended up solving it the old-fashioned way; perhaps it will benefit someone if I share it. Note, I could not get around yanking the foreign key check, so suggestions are still open for how this would best be executed on a production environment:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- disable a foreign keys check
UPDATE employee SET company = IFNULL(company,1);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Setting the company value to 1 just happens to be the desired value that corresponds to the foreign key index we needed in this case.